# How to get largest and smallest number in a sorted list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.3

```
def list_stats(values, num_int, low_range, high_range):  # function to fix
    values = generate_integer_list(num_int, low_range, high_range)
    new_val = values.sort()
    low_val = new_val[0]
    high_val = new_val[num_int - 1]
    total = 0
    i = 0
    for num in range(num_int-1):
        i = i + 1
        num = values[i]
        total = total + num
    avg = total/num_int
    return total, low_val, high_val, avg


def generate_integer_list(num_int, low_range, high_range): # generates random #'s
    values = []
    for count in range(num_int):
        number = random.randint(low_range, high_range)
        values.append(number)
    return values
```

I have to find the largest and smallest number in a generated list, get the total of the all numbers in the list and the average. My numbers are generated by generate_integer_list.

I've used the sort function to sort the generated list, and then grab the first and last number in that list for the smallest and largest. However, the values being returned are not in anyway correct. I've tried giving the sorted list a new name, but that does not work.

The only way i can return proper values is if i print the sorted list, but I am not allowed to do that with regards to the question. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your lowest and highest values would certainly be correct; your *total* and *average* values might not be. Perhaps you want to show us why you think you get incorrect values?

Comment: Every time I ran the function i would get values for smallest and largest that were not actually the smallest and largest inside the list; or even inside the list for that matter. I print the original generated list inside the main, so I can see the original list.

Comment: And how do you know what was *in* the list? You never print the list anywhere; each time you call `generate_integer_list()` you generate *new* random values, so you cannot check the results against that list.

Comment: for example: 

Enter the number of integers to generate: 10
Enter the low range: -100
Enter the high range: 100
 Values = [81, 74, -28, -38, -94, 9, -100, 96, -15, -24]

Comment: Your function calls `generate_integer_list()` *directly*, and uses the values. Are you calling the function somewhere else too?

Comment: If so, you'll get a *different* list (you get a different list each time you call that function). If you need to generate a random list *once*, then store the result of *one* call to `generate_integer_list()`, and pass that list to the `list_stats()` function directly. Don't generate a new list inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, me being inattentive ive called the generate_integer_list() once more in my main for some reason... that would explain the different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to calculate the total skips over the first value; just loop over the list of numbers *directly*, no need to create a range here:

```
total = 0
for num in values:
    total = total + num
```

You can do this without resorting to sorting; you already have to loop over all the numbers:

```
def list_stats(values, num_int, low_range, high_range):
    values = generate_integer_list(num_int, low_range, high_range)
    total = 0
    low_val = high_val = values[0]  # something to start with
    for num in values:
        total += num
        if num < low_val:
            low_val = num
        if num > high_val:
            high_val = num
    avg = total / num_int
    return total, low_val, high_val, avg
```

I replaced `total = total + num` with `total += num` as it comes down to the same thing for numbers.

I also started `low_val` and `high_val` off with the first value in the list of values; the loop will then find any lower or higher values as it goes along.

Comment: i dont understand how the decision structure would find the smallest and largest value, if theyre always equal to the first number

Comment: @user2939916: They are not; in the loop we look at *every* number. If any of those numbers are smaller than the current `low_val` number found so far, then they replace that number as the lowest value. Ditto for when any number is being bigger, it'll replace the previous highest found.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple BIFs that you could use to simplify this if that is the direction you choose.

```
sum(numlist) # the sum of your random list
sum(numlist) / len(numlist) # average your list
sorted(numlist, key=int)[0] # lowest element
numlist[len(numlist) - 1] # list is already sorted this gives you the max
```

Just quick snippets; I didn't rewrite your code.